# Upload large-sized data to Flask server through request.stream from frontend

Tags: flask, upload, frontend

### Problem Description

I'm currently having issues with uploading large files(size up to several gigabytes) to my flask server from frontend page, the possible solution I found is upload through `request.stream`. Here's the sample code I found in [[1]](http://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/):

```
# Upload file as stream to a file.
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    with open("/tmp/output_file", "bw") as f:
        chunk_size = 4096
        while True:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                return
            f.write(chunk)
```

The code works when I use the following curl command:

`curl -X POST -T 'sample.zip' 'http://localhost/upload'`

but it doesn't work with this one:

`curl -X POST -F 'file=@sample.zip' 'http://localhost/upload'`

In addition, I'd like to upload files from frontend, the official tutorial provides the following sample [[2]](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <input type=file name=file>
  <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

But I think (and tested) that the code above does not meet my requirements of uploading large size file through `request.stream`. Are there any suggestions or any other workaround? Thanks in advance!

#### Reference

1. [Flask File Streaming](http://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/)
2. [Flask - Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/)